# C++ HTTP GET Request return Null

Tags: c++, windows, http

Currently I am using **Wininet** to implement HTTP GET Request

Below I am trying to trigger a GET Request from a server that return a string of a timestamp

**`Goal`**:  Get the value of that string

> SEND GET REQUEST

```
HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpenA("MyAgent",
INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);

HINTERNET hConnect2 = InternetConnectA(hSession, "10.15.229.111",
   8732, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
HINTERNET hRequest2 = HttpOpenRequestA(hConnect2, "GET",
  "ovs/healthcheck", NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1);

HttpSendRequestA(hRequest2, NULL, 0, NULL , 0);
```

> TRY TO GET RESPONSE STRING

```
DWORD dwContentLen;
DWORD dwBufLen = sizeof(dwContentLen);
if (HttpQueryInfo(hRequest2,
                  HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH | HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER,
                  (LPVOID)&dwContentLen,
                  &dwBufLen,
                  0))
{
     DWORD dwReadSize = dwContentLen ;   

     DWORD dwBytesRead;
     char *pCopyPtr = pData;
     InternetReadFile(hRequest2, pCopyPtr, dwReadSize, &dwBytesRead);
     pCopyPtr =  dwBytesRead;

     unsigned char datareturn[20];
 memcpy(datareturn, &pData, 20);
 std::cout << datareturn;           }
```

Quick question : does pData return the response string from the GET request.

As a c++ newcomer, any insight would be great. Thank you for your time

Comment: Did you look at the contents of `pData`? Seems like a really simple thing to do in the debugger. You might also just read the whole thing all at once unless your healthcheck response is massive. It makes the code much simpler.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes, I try to set a break point, at pData, and it return null. May I know how to read the whole data.Thanks

Comment: Simple, you read it all at once, not in 11 pieces. Have you considered adding some error checking? If something fails before that and you ignore it I'm not surprised you don't get any data. Consider putting together a [mcve].

Comment: @RetiredNinja, have edited the code, still datareturn is null

Comment: Did you read Microsoft's documentation yet? [HTTP Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wininet/http-sessions), and in particular [Downloading Resources from the WWW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wininet/http-sessions#downloading-resources-from-the-www)